# Calculate log likelihood of Dirichlet distribution using Gamma distribution

Tags: dirichlet-distribution

> Let $X_1,\dots,X_{k+1}$ be mutually independent random variables, each having a gamma distribution with parameters $\alpha_i,i=1,2,\dots,k+1$ show that $Y_i=\frac{X_i}{X_1+\cdots+X_{k+1}},i=1,\dots,k$, have a joint ditribution as $\text{Dirichlet}(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots,\alpha_k;\alpha_{k+1})$

According to the above theorem, we can get Dirichlet random variables from Gamma distribution.
So, I think that it's possible to calculate log likelihood of Dirichlet Distribution using Gamma.

Let $\vec{X} = (X_1,X_2,...,X_n)$ be samples from $Gamma(\alpha_i, 1)$. Then we normalize $\vec{X}$ and get $\vec{Y}$. 
Then, Let $A = log\,p(\vec{X}) = \sum_{i=1}^nlog\,p(X_i) = \sum_{i=1}^n [(\alpha_i-1)\,log\,X_i - X_i - log\,\Gamma(\alpha_i)]\,$ 
 $B = log\,p(\vec{Y})=\Sigma_{i=1}^n[(\alpha_i-1)log\,Y_i-log\,\Gamma(\alpha_i)]+log\,\Gamma(\bar{\alpha}) = \Sigma_{i=1}^n[(\alpha_i-1)(logX_i-log\bar{X})-log\,\Gamma(\alpha_i)]-log\,\Gamma(\bar{\alpha})$.

With the calculation, I think the result says that $A \neq B$. I don't know why this happen. I think that dirichlet random variable $\vec{Y}$ comes from Gamma random variable $\vec{X}$. So, I think they have the same log likelihood, but they didn't. Would you expalin about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Gamma sample of $X_i\sim\text{Ga}(\alpha_i,1)$ differs from a Dirichlet sample $(Y_1,\ldots,Y_n)\sim\text{Dir}(\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n)$ and it is thus no surprise that the likelihood functions on $\mathbf \alpha$ differ.

More importantly, the Dirichlet sample contains *less* information about the $\alpha_i$'s than the Gamma sample since $\sum_i Y_i=1$. Intuitively, it looses one dimension. In other words, when observing the $X_i$'s, turning them into $Y_i$'s by a normalisation step is wasting away information. (The exact information matrix for both the Gamma and the Dirichlet [involves digamma functions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/7507/7224), hence making the comparison delicate.)

The quoted theorem is about simulation, exhibiting a connection between the distribution of the $X_i$'s and the distribution of the $Y_i$'s. But the $X_i$'s are *latent variables*  in statistical terms, they are not observed.

Comment: Then why the above theorem states that Dirichlet random variables can be sampled from Gamma random variables? is there any possibility to get Dirichlet likelihood from Gamma random variables?

Comment: Simulation and statistical inference are two different things. It is possible to simulate Dirichlet variates using Gamma variates as a marginalisation step. But it is not possible to recover the original Gamma variates by looking at the Dirichlet variates since the transform is not a bijection. This explains why inference (and likelihood) differ in the two settings.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. Can you recommend any materials that elaborate the difference between simulation and inference, or any related topics?